# Made a mistake with mysql restore on the production site instead of the staging one. Can I use mysql general log to restore?

Tags: mariadb, wai-aria

Made a mistake with mysql restore on the production site instead of the staging one. Can I use mysql general log to restore? It seems general log is all I have. I dont seem to have a binlog with MariaDB's Aria storage engine.

What should I do now? Anyone has any experience using general log to recover the database?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO offers support in database admin related questions like this. Pls pay attention when you have a MariaDB question because it is only similar to MySQL, but not the same! MySQL does not have aria table engine therefore the question is not applicable to MySQL.

Comment: Why don't use a backup (If you don't have one, did you consider to fire your DBA)? Why do you enable general log on production?

Comment: have a backup but that was 4 days worth of information, it's a testing site, not production ready yet so didnt do backups